# sorting ArrayList of objects on 3 int fields

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

My code below fails to sort the ArrayList based on first income, then age, then postCode.
I read many examples online but failed to come up with a working solution. Please help.

if a 4 persons list has int data which is simplified by a single digit as shown below.

- 1,2,3
- 0,0,0
- 1,3,4
- 1,3,2

  then it should sort them to be
- 0,0,0
- 1,2,3
- 1,3,2
- 1,3,4

Thank you

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
private int income;
private int age;
private int postCode;

public Person(){}
public Person(int income, int age, int postCode) {
    this.income = income;
    this.age = age;
    this.postCode = postCode;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = income;
    result = 31 * result + age;
    result = 31 * result + postCode;
    return result;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person another) {
    return ((Integer) income).compareTo(another.getArea());
}
```

}

Collections.sort(myList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int compareTo( Person another )
{
    if ( this.income == another.income )
    {
        if ( this.age == another.age )
        {
            return ((Integer) this.postCode).compareTo(another.postCode );
        }

        return ((Integer) this.age).compareTo(another.age );

    }

    return ((Integer) this.income).compareTo(another.income );
}
```